# Why is depth of field different in live view vs. video recording on my Canon 5D?

Tags: dslr, video, canon-5d-mark-ii, live-view

I recently got a Canon 5DmkII.

This weekend I was at the local high school football field playing with the camera and recording video. I set the camera down on the field, turned live view on, and pressed the focus button in order to focus on a soccer ball. In the live view, the depth of field was *amazing*. I was so excited to record. When I pressed the center button to record all of sudden the depth of field changed. It was not even close to what it looked like during in the live view before recording.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instructions](http://www.learn.usa.canon.com/resources/articles/2011/eos5dmarkii_moviemode_article.shtml)

I found that a setting wasn't set correctly.

The steps are reproduced below.

1. 2nd Set-up Menu (yellow tabs with wrench icon) > Live View/Movie Function Settings — Press SET button.
2. Select and highlight LV function setting —Press SET button.
3. Scroll to Stills + movie — Press SET button.
4. Screen settings: Scroll to Movie Display — Press SET button.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, LiveView is shot with the aperture wide open, hence minimum DoF. When actually shooting (or recording), the aperture closes down to whatever your setting is. Try setting to max aperture to record what liveview sees.

Comment: So just change it in AV mode? Thanks.

Comment: I do not actually shoot video myself, but I guess that yes, that's what you should do (or better yet, shoot manual, where appropriate, so your exposure remains consistent when the scene changes - like when you pan around a room).

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are not taking pictures or recording video, the camera sets the Aperture wide open, whether you are in live-view or not. This is in order to give the autofocus as much light as possible to work with (I don't know if there are other reasons).

Once you take a picture, or record video, the aperture changes to whatever you have selected.